# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate with multiple filter fields does not work with $lt

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to retrieve records that were last updated before the start of the day and update a field to manage concurrent process. Mongoose appears to be ignoring my $lt operator field filter. The rest of the filter is respected, but I get results with dates later the start of the day. If I use only the date as a filter, it will work, but not in combination with the other fields. Here's my code:

```
const get_capture_for_processing = async function (req, res) {
  req.params['active'] = true
  req.params['inprogress'] = false
  req.params['date'] = {$lt: new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0))}
  console.log(req.params)
  res.json(await Capture.findOneAndUpdate(req.params, {'inprogress':true}).sort({"elapsed": -1}))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of user error.

I finally checked the Capture schema, and it did not have a date field at all. The query returned the date field from Mongo, but apparently without the field in the model, it will not filter based on it.

Adding: `date: Date` to the model fixed the filtering.